# Making a function to return the frequency of words in text

Tags: python, regex, string, python-re

So ideally, my code involves around the idea making a list of the words that I call in the text. This is my code.

```
import re

def checkWord(regex):
    
  resList = []
  with open('wells.txt', 'r') as wordFile:
    for line in wordFile:
      if re.match(regex, line[:-1]):
          resList.append(line[:-1])
       

  return resList
```

However, my problem is that the code ends up printing the full line of where that word is and I just need the word itself. Here's the outcome

```
checkWord('He')



['He was full of speculation that night about the condition of Mars, and',
 'He remained standing at the edge of the pit that the Thing had made for',
 'Henderson stood up with his spade in his hand.',
 ]
```

Comment: I'm not sure if I understood. You want the ouput was `['He','He','Henderson']`?

Comment: If I'm not going crazy I think this was initially tagged as `pandas` and then removed? Would a pandas non-regex solution work? You could also use my list comprehesnion without pandas.

Comment: @AlexanderPacheco please accept one of the answers as solution by clicking the checkmark next to my answer. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can turn the below into a function, but you can use list comprehension after using `.split()`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Sentence' : ['He was full of speculation that night about the condition of Mars, and',
 'He remained standing at the edge of the pit that the Thing had made for',
 'Henderson stood up with his spade in his hand.']})
word = 'He'
df['words'] = (df['Sentence'].str.split()
               .apply(lambda x: sum([True for y in x if y == word])))

                                            Sentence  words
0  He was full of speculation that night about th...      1
1  He remained standing at the edge of the pit th...      1
2     Henderson stood up with his spade in his hand.      0
```

Essentially, you return a list of `True` boolean values for each match and then you `sum` them (Boolean `True` is the equivalent value of integer `1`).

If you want the sum of all rows, then simply do:

```
(df['Sentence'].str.split()
               .apply(lambda x: sum([True for y in x if y == word]))).sum()

2
```

Comment: it was not clear, but i think he want the words containing 'He', like `[He, He, Henderson]` instead of the full line

Comment: I mean, i think he would want just something like this `[word for word in resList if regex in word]`. But this could be propperly solved by doing the regex in the right way.

Comment: @FlavioMoraes I thought you were the OP. I have rolledback my edit until your question is clarified. And, the title says "Making a function to return the frequency of words in text". The OP seems to be interested in word count, so your comment and answer would not solve, as the key word in the question is `frequency`.

Comment: I see it, but at the same time he said "my problem is that the code ends up printing the full line of where that word is and I just need the word itself". The questions is not clear at all. We will have to wait and see.

Answer (score 0):

if you want the word you can use `'\w*{}\w*'.format(regex)`. I think this will do exactly what you want:

```
import re

def checkWord(regex):
    
  resList = []
  with open('wells.txt', 'r') as wordFile:
    for line in wordFile:
      resList+re.findall(r'\w*{}\w*'.format(regex), txt, flags=re.IGNORECASE)

  return resList
```

I used `re.IGNORECASE` but i'm not sure if you want to ignore case. You can remove it.